HTML field in a JSON response - Could there be any issue related to non-escaped chars?
Suppose an API returns JSON response like this
{"error":"","data":"xxx"}   

And in the place of xxx it returns HTML code/page.
Does this HTML need some escaping like HTML-escaping or JSON-escaping?
Is it better to be HTML-escaped or not?
Could this HTML in some cases break the JSON surrounding it, and if so what should be done for that not to happen?
I just wonder what the best practice is regarding this.
I tried finding some info about this on the web, but I am finding only some older pages, and no authoritative answer really. So I don't know what the best practice is as of now.

Any double-quote characters in the string would certainly need to be escaped, but I imagine that's about it.

@David Because the HTML is within a string property value, I guess, right? That is within double quotes? OK... I see... I hope that's the only scenario which would break the JSON.

JSON can encode any string, so also HTML.
The general rules of escaping characters in a string apply:

\, " and control characters need to be escaped.
You can write these in the \u???? format, so \u followed by the Unicode codepoint in four hexadecimal characters.
For some control characters there are alternative codes: \b, \f, \n, \r, \t.
Non-control characters can be escaped with a preceding backslash.

On the JSON producing side (the server that exposes the API) you would typically use a standard JSON library to encode strings (such as HTML) as JSON. As you tagged this with java, you would use a library like Jackson, Gson, et al.
Similarly, on the client side you'd use an established JSON parser.
If you use established JSON libraries, this should never lead to invalid JSON or a difference between the encoded and decoded string. You'd never want to do these tasks with custom-made code.
If it concerns HTML, you can of course opt to use HTML entities like &quote; instead of ",...etc, but then you really encode a different string. It is just that semantically these different strings have the same result when parsed by a HTML parser. Take care however, that HTML may contain content where you cannot use HTML entities. For instance, <script>"use strict"</script> is not the same as <script>&quot;use strict&quot;</script>. For this reason I would not take this approach. All you need are the JSON encoding/decoding mechanisms provided via standard libraries or even natively in some languages (like ECMAScript).
